# How to remake a SQL query in the Query Builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Working code

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT 
        galleries.user_id, 
        galleries.image,
        galleries.title 

        FROM galleries

        LEFT JOIN gallery_master ON gallery_master.gallery_id = galleries.id 

        WHERE gallery_master.master_id = 5

        ORDER BY galleries.id DESC');
```

I'm trying to remake and I get an error

```
$result = DB::table('galleries')
        ->leftJoin('gallery_master', 'gallery_master.gallery_id', '=', 'galleries.id ')
        ->select('galleries.user_id', 'galleries.image', 'galleries.title')
        ->where('gallery_master.master_id' = '5')
        ->paginate(20);
```

Error

```
 "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'galleries.id ' 
in 'on clause' 
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `galleries` 
left join `gallery_master` on `gallery_master`.`gallery_id` = `galleries`.`id `)
```

I don't know how to do that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove space from 'galleries.id'

try below query

```
$result = DB::table('galleries')
        ->select('galleries.user_id', 'galleries.image', 'galleries.title')
        ->leftJoin('gallery_master', 'gallery_master.gallery_id', '=', 'galleries.id') // from here
        ->where('gallery_master.master_id' = '5')
        ->paginate(20);
```